# shouldOverrideUrlLoading Will Load "file:///" But Not "http://" URL Parameters

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

Works:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/css-js/app.css");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Doesn't Work:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("http://yahoo.com");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Try [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845938/android-how-to-open-new-browser-from-webviewclient).  Could be that you need to set a browser intent

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem? If not, please give details.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is just that an infinite loop is being created. It re-overrides the new loadUrl each time. For example, this works without problems:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
{
    if(!url.toLowerCase().contains("yahoo.com"))
    {
        view.loadUrl("http://yahoo.com");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that simply saving the last override URL and comparing with `if(!url.equals(lastOverrideUrl))` will not work in this case (and many others), as the URL is automatically changed from "http://yahoo.com" to "http://www.yahoo.com/".